# Save playback from an embedded audio file

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio

I've done some digging on this already, but I can't seem to find a more simplistic way of saving the playback position for an embedded audio file. For example, if someone refreshes the page, instead of the audio starting again from the beginning, it will pick up where it left off.

I know that is involves using `localStorage`, but I'm not sure what's the *best* way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Set local storage var, read in that var each time with an if statement to display vid or not. Honestly, localstorage is not a great solution, if you used some sort of db you could store it and then pull that in. Most simplistic approach, localstorage.